# Google Maps Fullscreencontrol showing blank on Android and Chrome - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have integrated google maps in my ionic 2 project and it was working fine until I got the requirement to add the full screen option. I added the line, tested on google chrome, and when i clicked on full screen I got a blank screen. Compiled on Android, same problem. However it is working fine on Mozilla and IE. This is my code

```
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {

   let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.563910, 147.154312);

   let mapOptions = 
     {
       center: latLng,
       zoom: 5,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       fullscreenControl: true
     }

   this.map = google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

   this.mapCluster.addCluster(this.customersView.paginatedCustomers, this.map);

});
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: No I didn't. However, I created a new full screen page inside the application and redirected him when the users clicks on full screen icon.